# SQL parametrised query containing multiple options

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite

I would like to write a query

```
Select col1, col2 
from table 
where col1 = 'blah' or 'blah2' or 'blah3' 
  and col2 = 'blah' or 'blah2' or 'blah3'
```

I am used to writing them like this for a SINGLE option

```
select 
    col1, col2 
from 
    table 
where 
    col1 = :col1 and col2 = :col2

Parameters.AddWithValue(":col1", 'blah')
Parameters.AddWithValue(":col2", 'blah')
```

Now I want to add several options with OR between them and obviously the above code wont work. The SQL is for SQLite. Can anyone suggest how I could do this? I may potential have more then 3 different values for each parameter. I have tried searching but the answer is elusive.

Comment: You can take a look at [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause). It is for Sql Server but some of the answers are general enough that you can try with SQLite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to use complete expressions, i.e., you need to write `col1 =` or `col2 =` every time.

Alternative, use [IN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op):

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE col1 IN (:c11, :c12, :c13) AND col2 IN (:c21, :c22, :c23);
```